# passing NSManagedObjects between ViewControllers - random bad access errors

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

Is passing NSManagedObjects between ViewControllers a bad idea?  I have an iPad app and I seem to run into random bad access crashes and sigbart errors.

These NSManageObjects are coming from CoreData and I wonder if they sometimes just drop out of memory and cause this.  I was hoping to just pass them from controller to controller to avoid doing a fetch on every viewcontroller.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like it's a matter of bad object memory allocation practices. As long as you're not multithreading your app and there is only one managedObjectContext (typical), you can pass these NSManagedObjects between VeiwControllers no problem.

What's probably happening is you're passing the reference from one ViewController to another without incrementing it's refcount with a retain message. This can get dicey.

What I'd recommend is having a retain property on your ViewControllers, like

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObject *yourObject;
```

Then, when you get your managed object, keep it like this:

```
self.yourObject = ...;
```

... and when you want to pass it to another view controller:

```
otherViewController.yourObject = ...;
```

And it will take care of setting retain/release for you.

Comment: I added MBProgressHUD to my app, therefore adding in multithreading - thanks I wasn't even thinking about that.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're not following proper memory management semantics. You may want to read the [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html). If you're following the correct memory management rules then there's no reason at all for this to not be safe. You can't pass NSManagedObjects between threads, but as long as you're always on the same thread as the context (for view controllers that would be the main thread), then there should be no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure you don't retain the NSManagedObject context when you pass it to a new view controller. The best way to deal with this is to simply access to AppDelegate instance of managedObjectContext, using

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
```

If you assign this to a property, again, without using `retain`, you should be fine with memory management.